# Установить браузер в LXD контейнер и запустить ярлык браузера в главной ОС

Tags: linux, браузер, контейнеры

Пытаюсь установить браузер Brave в LXD контейнер (Voidlinux - в идеале, или LinuxMint), создать ярлык для браузера в моей ОС и запустить этим ярлыком браузер как любую программу, но с условием работы в контейнере. Не уверен как задать настройки display или lxc профиль на моей Линукс ОС (не убунту).

Пробовал следовать следующим материалам:

https://blog.simos.info/running-x11-software-in-lxd-containers/

например,

```
environment.PULSE_SERVER: unix:/home/ubuntu/pulse-native
connect: unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native
listen: unix:/home/ubuntu/pulse-native
```

что вместо ubuntu, user ставить в gentoo?

> lxc exec mycontainer -- sudo --user ubuntu --login
> а это не работает в voidlinux контейнере.

Comment: И что не получилось?

Comment: А почему не snap\flatpak, которые были созданы как раз для крослинуксового распространения?

Comment: @eri если запустить образ linuxMint, там просто поставить Brave. но в тех статьях делают x11.profile затем lxc exec mycontainer -- sudo --user ubuntu --login - это все не получилось, не могу сздать ярлык для браузера и запустить. В voidlinux сам brave  проблемно поставить, но то другая проблема.

Comment: @donRumata flatpak вместо lxd ? мне нужна максимальная безопасность. docker - вариант, но мне lxd более хорошим показался для этой задачи.

Comment: В snap вроде неплохо с изоляцией.